# How can I debounce renderPlot or any render* in shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The `renderPlot` seems to read `session$clientData$pixelratio`. This slows down my app when I'm zooming in on the browser (using `Ctrl + mousewheel` on Firefox) as the pixel ratio is constantly changing, and the plot gets rendered again when the ratio changes.

I'm wondering if there is a way to 'debounce' the whole plotting expression in `renderPlot`, such that it only renders when the pixel ratio is not changing after a few milliseconds (say 500ms)?

Apparently, [`shiny::debounce`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/debounce.html) (e.g. `debounce(renderPlot({...}), 500)`) doesn't work because `renderPlot({...})` is not an reactive expression. In the worst case scenario, I'll have to use `renderImage({...})` instead, but is there a quicker way to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1L)
someData <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10000),
                       y = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10000) + rnorm(10000))

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("graph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    ## some really expensive plotting
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x, y), someData) +
      geom_path(aes(x, y), someData) +
      geom_smooth(aes(x, y), someData)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How about using a graphing library with built-in zoom capabilities, such as [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/)?

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for the suggestion. That might be the way to go, but I'm trying to make my app fool proof. The users might inadvertently use browser-zoom and my app will crash if they do that.

Comment: Yes, but it won't crash using `plotly`, as it isn't recalculated on browser-zoom

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks. `plotly` does work. I initially thought the `renderPlotly` has the same semantic as `renderPlot` but luckily it doesn't. I'm happy to accept this as answer if you post it.